# BackgroundMediaPlayer throwing RPC server unavailable exception on Windows Phone 10

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-media-player, windows-10-mobile

When I use my Windows Phone 8.1 app in Windows Phone 10, the `BackgroundMediaPlayer` is throwing

> The RPC server is unavailable exception

on this piece of code:

```
var mediaPlayer = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current;
```

But it works fine on Windows Phone 8.1. How to resolve this error for my app while using in Windows Phone 10. Please help me.